# Textview not showing anything from JSON Object

Tags: android, json

Response from android is good which is the database i choose based on some value

```
Response: {"users":[{"id":"6","unique_id":"5f8fb2d3ee71c9.27038026","name":"siapa","email":"aku","encrypted_password":"G2HXPazvWEKRdm6lo5IDs4KSDEQ5ZTdlYjgyODBj","salt":"9e7eb8280c","created_at":"2020-10-21 11:02:27","updated_at":"2020-10-21 20:24:19"}]}
```

i need to show only object "updated_at" in textview but didnt show anything
this is my json code

```
private void getData() {
    String tag_string_req = "get";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list_data;
    list_data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.GET,
            AppConfig.URL_GET, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("users");
                for (int a = 0; a < jsonArray.length(); a++) {
                   JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(a);
                   HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("updated_at", json.getString("updated_at"));
                    list_data.add(map);
                }
                    update_time.setText(list_data.get(0).get("updated_at"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

what could be wrong?

Comment: Hello rizkyisya, have you tried setting up some logs to help you to find you issue?
You can add a log message using the following link: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.
Set up some logs, and if you still can't find the issue, write a comment here and I can check it later. :)

Comment: i set up some logs as u suggested but there is no error message in logcat

Comment: Can you share the updated code in the question? :)

Comment: The code aparently is good, you should trace the code with the debugger and see where it get lost.

Comment: im already figured out, the problem is in my php code, when im trying to acces php file with url in browser the array is not appear even though in android response is appear, so thats the problem. Thx for trying help me